# How to remove overlapping contours and separate each character as an individual contour for character extraction?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, mser

I am trying to implement character extraction from images in Python using the `MSER` in `opencv`. This is my code till now:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# create MSER object
mser = cv2.MSER_create()
# convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# detect the regions
regions,_ = mser.detectRegions(gray)
# find convex hulls of the regions
hulls = [cv2.convexHull(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]
# initialize threshold area of the contours
ThresholdContourArea = 10000
# initialize empty list for the characters and their locations
char = []
loc =[]
# get the character part of the image and it's location if the area of contour less than threshold
for contour in hulls:
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) > ThresholdContourArea:
        continue
    # get the bounding rectangle around the contour
    bound_rect = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    loc.append(bound_rect)
    det_char = gray[bound_rect[1]:bound_rect[1]+bound_rect[3],bound_rect[0]:bound_rect[0]+bound_rect[2]]
    char.append(det_char)
```

But this method gives multiple contours for the same letter and at some places multiple words are put into one contour. Here is an eg:
original image:

[image]

After adding the contours:

[image]

Here the first T has multiple contours around and the two rs are combined into one contour. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Why are you using MSER  instead of some kind of thresholding?

Comment: then how to extract the letters? I tried the `cv2.findContours()` function but it only returns the outermost contour

Comment: Can you post your original image?

Comment: @Ziri added the original image

Comment: findContours gives you all the letters. You only need to set hierarchies correctly. This source helps you with that: 
 https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `MSER`, here's a simple approach using thresholding + contour filtering. We first remove the border then Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image. The idea is that each letter should be an individual contour. We find contours and draw each rectangle.

Removed border `->` binary image `->` result

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Note:** In some cases, the letters are connected so to remove the merged characters, we can first enlarge the image using `imutils.resize()` then perform [erosion](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#erosion) or [morphological opening](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#opening) to separate each character. However, I was unable to obtain great results since the text would disappear even with the smallest sized kernel.

Code

```
import cv2
import imutils

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)

# Remove border
kernel_vertical = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
temp1 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_vertical)
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
temp2 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, horizontal_kernel)
temp3 = cv2.add(temp1, temp2)
result = cv2.add(temp3, image)

# Convert to grayscale and Otsu's threshold
gray = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and filter using contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```