# Unable to extract numbers using findContours opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am trying to extract handwritten numbers and alphabet from an image, for that i followed [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484793/how-to-remove-overlapping-contours-and-separate-each-character-as-an-individual)
but it is still not extracting the numbers and alphabet properly and picking up the border line as well.

You can find the result below:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import imutils

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('xxx/ocr/pic_crop_2.png')
image = imutils.resize(image, width=375)
img=image.copy()

# Remove border
kernel_vertical = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
temp1 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_vertical)
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
temp2 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, horizontal_kernel)
temp3 = cv2.add(temp1, temp2)
result = cv2.add(temp3, image)

# Convert to grayscale and Otsu's threshold
gray = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# thresh=cv2.dilate(thresh,None,iterations=1)

# Find contours and filter using contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[0]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('img', img)

cv2.waitKey()
```

I tried to use dialate but no luck.
Please find the sample image below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you Can Check the Contour Area For Fix That.

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('pic_crop_2.png')
#image = cv2.resize(image, width=375)
img=image.copy()

# Remove border
kernel_vertical = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
temp1 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_vertical)
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
temp2 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, horizontal_kernel)
temp3 = cv2.add(temp1, temp2)
result = cv2.add(temp3, image)

# Convert to grayscale and Otsu's threshold
gray = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# thresh=cv2.dilate(thresh,None,iterations=1)

# Find contours and filter using contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[0]
MIN_AREA=200
for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c)>MIN_AREA:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('img', img)

cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

3x3 closing and binarization give good results, it seems (thought the black area is problematic and should be erased or cropped explicitly).

[image]

Comment: Can you help me how can i achieve that through code ? An example or link would be helpful.

Comment: can you please share the code which gave you the above image as result ? it will be a great help

Comment: @Ironman: made with proprietary sw. But you already have all it takes.